# UIActivityViewController not working with WKWebView

Tags: swift, webkit, share, wkwebview, uiactivityviewcontroller

How to implement UIActivityViewController for WKWebView in swift?

I have following UIActivityViewController implementation, unfortunately the ActivityView for **sharing action** is not displayed.

**CODE UPDATE:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.loadView();
}

override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    webView.allowsLinkPreview = true

    let items = [url]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items , applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

...

}
```

Comment: May I know, Where is your placed?

Comment: @IMHiteshSurani I add a code update in my question

Comment: You just need to add sharing code in viewDidAppper instead of viewDidLoad method. I will add detais code later

Answer (score 0):

You can not `present` a controller in `viewDidLoad`

## Code:

```
var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      loadCMSData()
  }

fileprivate func loadCMSData(){
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    webView.allowsLinkPreview = true
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
    let items = [url]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items , applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```